# Dirichlet’s Theorem and Solutions to Laplace Equation in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: electrostatics, terminology, fourier-transform, mathematics, differential-equations

I have been reading **Introduction to Electrodynamics - Griffiths** about solving Laplace equation in cartesian coordinates, and in that book, I saw this statement:

> The functions $\sin(n\pi y/a)$ are complete on the interval $0 \leq y \leq a$. It was this fact,
> guaranteed by Dirichlet’s theorem, that assured us Eq. $3.31$ could be satisfied,
> given the proper choice of the coefficients $C_n$.

I cannot understand the **Dirichlet's Theorem** that he mentioned here.

As far as I have searched, two of Dirichlet's Theorem are closely related to this problem. One is **Dirichlet's Boundary Condition**, and other is **Dirichlet-Jordan Test**

So, can anyone please explain what **Dirichlet's Theorem** means in this context?

Comment: probably this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%E2%80%93Jordan_test

Comment: Don't use images for text and Math. Just type it.

Comment: At the "Dirichlet's theorem" in this text there  is also a footnote referencing the book:  Boas. M.. Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, 2nd ed. (New York: John Wiley, 1983). Why don't you look it up?

Comment: One of the reasons I never looked it up is that I don't have a copy of M. Boas's book.

Comment: Internet Archive is a non-profit, making a lot of content free.  I believe it is legit, please correct me if I'm wrong.  https://archive.org/details/mathematicalmeth00boas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve the kind of boundary value problems like those encountered in Griffith's text concerning the Laplace operator, you often end up expressing your solution in terms of Fourier series. Dirichlet's theorem claims that any
$2\pi$ periodic function $f(x)$, even one with discontinuities, can be expressed as a Fourier series and that the series converges to $f(x)$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. There are many kinds of "convergence" however in mathematics, and the kind that Dirichlet's theorem guarantees is "convergence in the mean":
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{f(x+\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon)\over 2}.$$
Basically as you take more and more partial sums of the series, the sum approaches some value that is like the average value of the function in a small neighborhood of the point in question. So Dirichlet's theorem guarantees a special kind of point-wise convergence for the Fourier series, something that Fourier assumed or conjectured but Dirichlet rigorously proved.

Griffiths speaks of Dirichlet's theorem as a statement of the "completeness" of the functions $\sin(n\pi y/a)$. Here Griffith's is thinking in terms of the theory of $L^2$ spaces, of which Fourier series and Dirichlet's theorem are antecedent. Essentially, $L^2$ spaces are a kind of Hilbert space and Dirichlet's theorem is replaced by the more general Riesz-Fisher theorem. At any rate, completeness amounts to the same as saying that any function can be expanded in terms of linear combinations of *all* of the above trigonometric functions, i.e. the functions $\sin(n\pi y/a)$ form a basis of the infinite dimensional $L^2(0,a)$ space.

So when you are solving the Laplace operator for Dirichlet boundary conditions, and you find that you are able to write your solution as a Fourier expansion of a periodic function, then you can rest easy that the series you have obtained actually converges at each point in the interval to the physical solution of the problem at hand. Although the theorem is not easy to prove, it is easy to use and should be a part of every physicist's tool kit.

Comment: typo: the $\sin(n\pi y/a)$ do not form a basis for $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ (and you probably mean to set $a=1$? that would imply by oddness that all $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f=0$, which is obviously false). What we do have (and probably what you intended) is that $\{\sin (ny)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ does form a basis for $L^2(0,\pi)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for pointing that out. I meant to point out that the functions $\sin(n\pi y/a)$ will form a basis for $L^2(0,a)$. That edit should fix the problem right?

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem regarding convergence of the associated Fourier series is not unconditional, it is a sufficient condition (the "Dirichlet condition") for functions that are piece-wise continuous and have finite number of monotonic segments. It can be extended (Jordan) to include functions of bounded variation. For example $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not such a function.